# Can I update links retrieved with Get-ItemReference in powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm building some scripts that will check that items are localized to a particular branch of the content tree (we have lots of parallel tree structures and we want to copy between them) and can successfully retrieve all links/references an item contains using Get-ItemReference with the -ItemLink parameter.

Is there a command I can use on the links returned to update them to refer to  different items?

The closest I can find is Update-ItemReferrer though this seems to be the reverse (updates items that point to a specific item) and also possibly deprecated (I get a no command found error, and the page in the gitbook has format issues https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/update-itemreferrer )

So are the link/reference objects returned able to be updated directly, or do I need to use them to find the fields on the item itself and update there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this example point you in the right direction?

**Example:** The following re-links images.

```powershell
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\images\koala"
$itemNew = Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\images\penguins"
$links = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $item -ItemLink
foreach($link in $links) {
    $linkedItem = Get-Item -Path master:\ -ID $link.SourceItemID 
    $itemField = $linkedItem.Fields[$link.SourceFieldID]
    $field = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.FieldTypeManager]::GetField($itemField)

    $linkedItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $field.Relink($link, $itemNew)
    $linkedItem.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null
}
```

Check out the gist here:
https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/f563b0b3597f6c0a75d6

**Example:** The following gets the list of references to the item.

```powershell
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home\sample item 1"
$links = Get-ItemReference -Item $item -ItemLink
foreach($link in $links) {
    # Filter out the links you care about and relink if necessary
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works - though I'll be using Get-ItemReferences, as I'm going in the other direction, so I'll have begin/end edit outside the foreach. I was hoping the link objects themselves were editable, but using them to grab the correct fields will also work. I'm assuming the $field.Relink method works on Rich text fields with multiple links?